# How do I use a kickstart script from RedHat in Ubuntu without altering the ISO

Tags: system-installation, kickstart

I'm trying to automate the Ubuntu installation process as part of a migration from RedHat, and I have a working kickstart script that I would like to modify for Ubuntu.

I have read several answers here and official Ubuntu tutorials, so I did manage to use the graphical tool to generate the KS script. However, I don't want to alter the ISO image at this point; instead I want to load the KS script from the installation menu. In RedHat you need only press e and then indicate the path to the script (currently hosted in an HTTP server).

Is there a way to do this in Ubuntu? My plan is to test the script in Virtualbox until I get the desired result, and alter the ISO only then.

Comment: Upon booting to the ISO it will give you Try.... Try...Without Installing, etc. Arrow to the one you want then press F6 then press ESC it gives you the boot line right there in edit mode ready to go.  When done with your modifications you just press Enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ubuntu, it is called a *preseed* file.

There are several ways to tell the installer to use a preseed file:

- place it in the boot image as `preeseed.cfg` (which you don't want to do) or reference it on the kernel command line as `preseed/file=/cdrom/preseed2.cfg`
- add the preseed to the installer's initrd (probably not what you want)
- reference it in the kernel command line as `preseed/url=http://host/path/to/preseed.cfg` (This could be hand edited after booting the installer image to the menu.)
- supply the path to the preseed file in dhcp using option vendor-class-identifier="d-i" and filename="url"  (Note: it may be a good idea to scope this carefully.)
- If you were network booting rather than booting an ISO image, you could also supply the preseed path in the kernel command line in the pxe boot config file

Comment: The preseed file is Ubuntu-specific, I'd have to review the documentation and learn how to use that one. What I'm looking for at the moment is a means to run the adapted kicstart file from RedHat.

Comment: Kickstart is specific to RedHat, but this looks promising: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KickstartCompatibility